# Prepending an HTML element to the start of parent node

Tags: html, dom

I have an HTML/JS page with the following structure:

```
<div id='divid'>
    <span id='one'>...</span>
    <span id='two'>...</span>
    <span id='three'>...</span>
    <span id='four'>...</span>
</div>
```

I would like to place the span with **id='four'** as the first element child of div. I have tried using the following commands but still failed.

```
divDOM = document.getElementById('divid');
divDOM.prepend(document.getElementById('four'));
```

as well as:

```
divDOM = document.getElementById('divid');
divDOM.insertBefore(document.getElementById('four'), divDOM.childNodes[0]);
```

and

```
divDOM = document.getElementById('divid');
divDOM.insertBefore(document.getElementById('four'), divDOM.firstChild);
```

But all these steps I have failed to move the span element with id='four' to the first position. What have I been doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
const clone = document.querySelector('#divid').children[3].cloneNode(true)

document.querySelector('#divid').children[3].remove()

document.querySelector('#divid').prepend(clone)
```

Clone selected node and then remove selected node from dom.
So just prepend a clone.

Comment: thanks! actually the code i wrote worked too. i was just calling from the wrong function :D